# How can the section alignment in IEEEtran be adjusted for left alignment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, ieeetran

I want to put our section in center to left

How could I possible achieve this in this kind of TeX document?

```
\documentclass[conference,a4paper,10pt]{IEEEtran}
```

I have put this fragment into my TeX document:

```
\section{INTRODUCTION}
```

The result looks like this (centered instead of left aligned):

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

The `IEEEtran` class *explicitly* sets `\centering`.

If you want to risk rejection of your paper, you can use a patch.

```latex
\documentclass[conference,a4paper,10pt]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

% remove \centering from \section
\patchcmd{\section}{\centering}{}{}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try `titlesec` package

```
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\filright\raggedright}
{\thesection.}
{6pt}
{\fontsize{12pt}{13pt}\selectfont{\sc #1}}
[]
```

copy the above code inside your preamble.

Hope this works

Comment: Thank you so much